# Problem in training my MNIST model in Keras

Tags: conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I have prepared a sequential model using Tensorflow for recognizing digits. But after compiling the model whenever I try to train my model, it shows only 1875 training sample; though when I print its length, it shows me the length of 60000 samples.
Can't figure out why this occurs?
Any hint please!

My code:
[image]

Comment: Default batch size is 32. So 1875 * 32 = 60.000

Comment: Oops, really forget about "batch_size" parameter.  Now its work. Thank you @Frightera.